Why do most philosophers of religion believe in God?
When philosophers at large are surveyed, we observe this distribution:

N = 1771 (source)
But when we filter by area of specialization (AOS) = philosophy of religion, we observe this distribution instead:

N = 141 (source)
Why?

Because philosophers who believe in God are much more likely to specialize in philosophy of religion.

Yeah, seems like a self selection bias. You wouldn't be surprised to find that most people who study astrology believe in astrology.

People probably aren't going to be that inclined to dedicate their life to something they don't believe is true.
There is still some value in understanding the foundations of religious belief, even if one doesn't hold those beliefs. It has significantly impacted society (and continues to do so) in terms of how people think and what they believe (beyond "does a god exist"). Some people may also have become atheist during their studies. There may also be other factors, like pressure from family. All of this would account for the atheists specialising in philosophy of religion.
One might also speculate about the further education of religious people who studied theology. Philosophy of religion would be a fairly closely-related subject that could be a natural extension of their education. So that could shift the scale towards theism.

@Lowri It's some reasoned inferences based on the data. Short of much more specific survey that asks detailed questions about people's motivations, that's probably the best we're going to get.

Agreed that intuition/guess is the best we can do without going back and surveying those philosophers.  If the answer is important to you, perhaps you should contact the folks running this survey and ask them to add a suitable question to the 2025 version. It certainly makes sense to me that the people who go into philosophy of religion consider religion important, which would tend to skew toward those who have one. The minority (non-theist) voices would likely be those who consider religion important due to its impact on society and history, and on the evolution of philosophy.

Minor nitpick: religion does not necessarily have to be theistic, much less monotheistic. So an atheist person might be deeply religious and thus interested in studying philosophy of religion. On the other hand, I suspect academic philosophers tend to be more western-raised, where abrahamic religions are far more prevalent, which is why this bias is so pronounced regardless.

Or (although I am really speculating at this point, I have little knowledge of contemporary phiosophy of religion) perhaps philosophy of religion itself is heavily biased in favour of studying theistic religion.

@tomasz where do you find a definition of religion that excludes the supernatural?

Self-Selection Bias + specific source of statistics
Well, because individuals drawn to the study of philosophy of religion may already have a pre-existing interest in or leaning towards religious belief. They might be seeking to philosophically defend or explore their existing faith, rather than critically examine it from a neutral standpoint. This creates a self-selection bias in the field
So it has nothing to do with studying philosophy, it has to do with them being indoctrinated first and then studying philosophy.
Also look at your source - This site summarizes the results of the 2020 PhilPapers Survey, which surveyed the philosophical views of 1785 English-speaking philosophers from around the world
It means most of them are probably from USA, where religion and Christianity is very widespread. If you take this poll in China or Scandinavia (or let's imagine USSR in the 1965) you can get pretty different results as we can see their more pure scientific interest on the matter.

To your point, here are the demographics: https://survey2020.philpeople.org/survey/results/demographics

People often dedicate their lives to investigating phenomena they don't understand.
There is also value in understanding the foundations of religious belief, especially for those that hold those beliefs. And people may have become theist during their studies. There may also be other factors, like pressure from peers and the academic community. All of this would account for the theists specialising in philosophy of religion.

I would love to find out if more philosophers of religion start out religious and end up non religious, or the reverse.

More people dedicate themselves to defending beliefs they don't want to abandon.

I'd like to suggest another perspective. Studying philosophy of religion as a non-believer may just not be fun.
Consider one of the most well known atheist philosophers: Richard Dawkins. It must be a terribly grueling life, participating in so many debates with religious scholars. Like being an abolitionist in the 19th century American south -- you're arguing against a position heald by the vast majority of the public.
And incredibly frustrating, because you know that you're not likely to persuade very many people. Religious people tend to be indoctrinated early in their lives, so it has become a core of their personality. This is difficult to excise. There are stories of people leaving their religions, but they're newsworthy precisely because they're the exception not the rule.

Personality is definitely overrated.

This may be true of some people. However, it is not true of all people, because it is not true of me (I am not a philosopher of religion, though. But I would find that occupation fun). I enjoy learning about religion because it is fascinating to me, in the same way as how many others find Egyptian and Greek mythology fascinating despite not believing in it. I don't feel the need to convince others that their beliefs are wrong. In fact, I feel like people believing in religion may be healthy for them, and convincing them otherwise may be doing them a disservice, even if it would be more "true".

@ZerGreenOne The question wasn't about "all people". It was about a general tendency.

And of course it would be ridiculous to assume there's just a single reason for anything related to human activities. My answer was not intended to refute anything in other answers, just to present another reason that applies to some philosophers.

The same reason that most soldiers believe that it is sometimes ethical to kill people
Self selection
People who have a strong ethical position against taking another’s life do not voluntarily join the military. People who do not believe in a divine being do not usually devote their life to studying religion.

studying religion is studying an important social tool and important myths. It has nothing to do with being a priest and brainwashing people with these myths. So your comparison isn't really logical

@Groovy: The argument is that for an atheist religion isn’t really important or interesting. I think the only reason why an atheist would study it is because they don’t understand it and can’t conceive it. Like a blind person who studies optics.

If you find religion not important, you are naive :) Religion is one of the most influential social constructs and tools of influence. This fact has nothing to do with being or not being atheist, as religion is a separate case of ideology. If you study imagined realities and myths, national, racial, religious etc, you of course study religion. Mor4eover blind people here are the ones who are inside religion ofc, because it's them who are under control. According to you it's mental patients who really understand illnesses cause they have them. Which is funny and sad. :)

@Groovy I never said religion wasn’t important or interesting, but you can’t study everything and a religious person is more likely to be drawn to study it than a non-religious person. Sport is important or interesting, but a person who isn’t interested in playing sport is unlikely to choose a career studying it.

@Groovy you can study religion without being a philosopher of religion.  Examples: sociologists and cultural anthropologists.

Would you study astrology? Quite a lot of people believe in it.

Part of the reason is already mentioned by responders. But they seem to have left out one important academic observation. Those who specialize in philosophy of religion are the ones who get to follow up on the debate and realize that historical arguments against existence of God are incomplete or not as strong as its advocates believe them to be, and that there are good counter arguments that salvage or even justify belief in God.
The problem of evil for example is resolved by highlighting the Divine allowance of free will which is only meaningful when possibility of moral evil is allowed to mankind. Natural evils are in turn justified by observing that the natural world is deliberately ordained by God to be a realm of trials and tribulations as opposed to the Paradise only which is the realm of absolute safety and enjoyment for mankind. Ultimately these relative evils are said to follow good final teloes that are fully known only to God but still partially open to human discovery. These thoughts allow religious people to keep their faith while being intellectually consistent.
On the contrary, theist philosophers can clearly see the toll that atheism exacts on ethics. It is convenient to cite horrors created by atheist ideologies such as Communism as being a consequence of their cold atheistic view of humanity.
Further it is argued that outside a theological framework, it is difficult to sustain an ethics that is not so relative to be meaningless. Moreover, many religious doctrines seem to realize very important moral goods in human worldly life, like sanctity of marriage, honesty, charity, etc.
The atheist argument that atheists too can and do observe some of these moral practices is countered by empirical data showing that religious people are significantly more likely to observe the moral practices that were originally inspired and popularized by world religions to begin with. Belief in God is said to provide a uniquely powerful motivation for ethical conduct, which can never be rivaled by atheism.
Theist philosophers would further point to detrimental consequences of irreligious cultural changes over recent decades advocated by secular/atheist movements such as Women's Lib and the Sexual Revolution; consequences like increase in mental health issues among children raised in dysfunctional families or born out of wedlock, similar ills associated with irreligious ways of sexual satisfaction such as porn and masturbation that are becoming increasingly more clear despite earlier denials by a lagging secular scientific establishment.
Philosophers of religion often continue to believe that argument from design for God is a valid explanation for the incredible productive complexity and order that we observe in the natural world at all levels of existence from microscopic phenomena to the cosmic systems.
These scholars are also particularly inclined to look deep into those supposed anomalies of human experience that are conveniently believed to be "proof of heaven" by the religious commoners. Accounts of religious/mystical/near-death experiences are deeply probed for demonstrating a unique phenomenology that is so difficult to dismiss by atheists' convenient ascription to hallucinations wrought by religious conditioning. Cases in point are such experiences in non-religious people, common meaningful elements across different religions, feelings of ineffable, incomparable bliss, unconditional love and profound veridical sense that usually produce profound transformative after-effects in the experiencers who report becoming deeply spiritual after the experiences. It is difficult to see how some chemical interactions in the brain or cultural conditioning can create these profound life-changing experiences that are incomparable to our known psychological phenomena.
As for NDEs, veridical observations of the physical surroundings obtained under general anesthesia or cardiac arrest, verified by the attending medical teams or family members are cited as proof of non-physical, spiritual forms of cognition, confirming religious belief in immaterial soul or life after death.
Arguments for mind-body dualism (soul) are held up by pointing to failures of physicalist positions to undermine the very strong common intuition for mind-body duality and efficacy of human will and mind. Instead, the theist philosophers rather focus on finding solutions for the question of mind-body interaction that has been the real problem for the dualist position.
Therefore, the responders here have to appreciate that while prior motivation does bias these academics towards the belief in God but it also produces a dedication to really follow up the actual questions of the debate to only realize that atheist arguments do not really hold much water when examined to the full. And then it matters to recognize how the bias on the other side, that is, the atheist assumption that religions have to be little more than ridiculous dogma, prevents many atheists from even looking into academic theist positions to appreciate their merits.

Comments have been moved to chat; please do not continue the discussion here. Before posting a comment below this one, please review the purposes of comments. Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an answer, on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.
